# Battery percentage inaccurate

Tags: vanilla-android

I have a rooted Galaxy Nexus (maguro) runnung an AOSP 4.4.4 rom and Franko.Kernel r396. I also have Gravity Box installed and have replaced the battery percent icon with the circle battery. As far as I can tell, these are the important factors relating to my issue. I have an app that shows battery voltage next to percent, and at 50% the voltage is 3600, but from what I've seen 3600 is supposed to be zero. If my battery falls below 50%, I have to keep my screen off or the phone dies instantly with no warning.

Answer (score 0):

Let me simplify since I see we have debaters.

You should calibrate your battery:

After you use your battery, as low as it will go, below 20%. Plug it into A/C Power until it is definitely fully charged. Wait an extra 20 minutes to make sure that it is fully charged. Then you need to:

1) Remove the battery stats file:
`rm /data/system/batterystats.bin`

This will prevent you from seeing any discrepancies in the usage of your battery & the battery stats.

2) Wipe the dalvik cache: 
`rm /data/dalvik-cache/*`

You stated that an app is showing your voltage levels as being correct, so you may need the app's cache cleared.

3) Then Reboot:
`reboot`

This is what causes the kernel to re-calibrate your battery, when the phone is rebooted after a full charge.

Comment: Can you cite the reason for this extra waiting for 20 minutes (would 0<X<20 or 20<X<(20-30) work as well)? That would be very helpful here. :-)

Comment: Thank you for that comment. I added a bit more why I do that, and why 20 minutes. Over should be fine. Possibly less, but as I stated, the script that I have always waits 20 minutes when set to auto. I wish I had a more technical reason for the time, but that is it. The truth. :)

Comment: Removing the `batterystats.bin` is not related at all (yeah, the good old calibration myth). That file just holds statistics on how apps were using the battery – not how the battery was depleted. Secondly: could you please explain what the Dalvik cache should have to do with it – and if it really is related (which I doubt), what would be the equivalent with ART (Android 5+)? Third: For a calibration, the battery must be "depleted" first (discharged to ~5..10%), as otherwise there won't be a complete charging cycle.

Comment: References: Start with our [calibration tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/calibration/info) and especially our [battery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery/info) and follow up their links. Reference concerning `batterystats.bin`: find it [explained by Google developer Dianne Hackborne](https://plus.google.com/u/0/105051985738280261832/posts/FV3LVtdVxPT) :)

Comment: I added more info for you. I know the batterystats.bin file removal does not calibrate your battery. That is why I had more than just that listed. As you can see it is the act of rebooting when the device is fully charged that will re-calibrate it after being below 20%.

Comment: I tried rebooting after a full charge, no difference. I changed kernels to GraKernel and now I get it down to 30% before it dies.

Comment: When you rebooted after a full charge, did you try letting it go as low as possible. I believe it is supposed to be below 20% to calibrate.